# Creating a chart in C# WinForms .NET 6

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-core, charts

So I'm trying to create a chart in my .NET 6 WinForm application, and I can't find the charts option in my toolbox. Does anyone know why it is doing it? Did they remove charts in .NET 6? And if so, how can I create a chart? Thanks

Comment: MSChart should be in the Data section.

Comment: Well, it isn't there

Comment: Then your installation is not correct or maybe you are not really creating a WinForms project.

Comment: Have you read https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/port-the-ms-chart-conmtrol-to-dot-net-core/1116076 - it gives some pointers about what to install ..

Comment: stuartd. I see... If so, are there any alternatives for the Microsoft library of charts?

Comment: Caius Jard I did actually read the thread about it. I've downloaded the library, but it still isn't shown in the toolbox. I can only make it by creating a chart object in the code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kirsan created a fork that works with .NET 6

https://github.com/kirsan31/winforms-datavisualization

Comment: Thank you VERY VERY much for suggesting this fork. It solved a big issue of mine. I ported my Win Forms application from .Net Framework to .Net 7 and charts were not working. I have spent so many hours during the last two weeks but could not find a solution. This fork is working fine in .Net 7

Answer (score 2):

So, I found a work-around. It's not the most elegant, nor particularly performant, but since I just wanted a quick visualisation tool for internal testing, this did the trick nicely. Here's what I ended up with (basic scatter plot, but the principle can be adapted for line charts and box charts etc):

[image]

### Process

1. Add a picture box to your form
2. populate it with an empty bitmap to the scale that you want to display
3. for each data point you want to plot, draw a circle on the bitmap at those coordinates using Graphics.DrawEllipse

### Example Code

```
    private void PlotCoordinates(List<Coordinates> coordinateList, Pen pen)
    {
        List<Rectangle> boundingBoxes = GenerateBoundingBoxes(coordinateList);

        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(image))
        {
            foreach (Rectangle boundingBox in boundingBoxes)
            {
                g.DrawEllipse(pen, boundingBox);
            }
        }
    }

    private List<Rectangle> GenerateBoundingBoxes(List<Coordinates> coordinateList)
    {
        var boundingBoxes = new List<Rectangle>(coordinateList.Count);

        //dataPointDiameterPixels is the diameter you want your ellipse to be on the plot
        //it needs to be an odd to be accurate
        int dataPointCetralisingOffset = dataPointDiameterPixels / 2;
        int rectLength = dataPointDiameterPixels;

        foreach (Coordinates coordinates in coordinateList)
        {
            int topLeftX = Maths.Max(coordinates.X - dataPointCetralisingOffset, 0);
            int topLeftY = Maths.Max(coordinates.Y - dataPointCetralisingOffset, 0);

            var box = new Rectangle(topLeftX, topLeftY, rectLength, rectLength);
            boundingBoxes.Add(box);
        }

        return boundingBoxes;
    }
```

Comment: That's a pretty interesting way of going around this problem. Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

WinForms has been depreciated and a lot of its functionality hasn't made it into .NET 6. There are no plans to change this. If you find an alternative solution please share it.

See this for more info: https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/discussions/6163

Comment: Winforms *charts* has been deprecated.