# I am using Visual Studio 2022 Community edition. My Chart control is grey, can not be draged on the form

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022

I create a project with Winforms. I want to use the chart control in my project, but it is grey. The target framework of my project is .NET 6.0. I really need some help. I am using Visual Studio 2022 Community edition.

How can I make the chart control available?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72251237/creating-a-chart-in-c-sharp-winforms-net-6

Comment: If my answer is helpful to you, you can mark it so that it can help more people.

Answer (score 1):

The chart control of Winforms only exists in Winforms (.net framework). You need to create a Windows Forms Application (.net framework) to use the chart control.

As follows:

[image]

[image]

If you want to create a chart in .net 6.0, you can refer to: [Creating a chart in C# WinForms .NET 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72251237/creating-a-chart-in-c-sharp-winforms-net-6)

Comment: Yes, thank u, I choose the wrong one